# USA PERM Processing EB-2/EB-#/Other?

Tags: usa, resident-permit, greencard, education

I did B.Sc. (IT) from India and have 10 years or working experience after that. My employer is filing USA Green card for me. However I have been told that since my graduation was only 3 years I'm not eligible for PERM processing.

After 10th grade,

- Diploma full time 3 years course
- B.Sc. IT full time 3 years course (I needed to do only 2nd and 3rd year since I had diploma)
- MBA IT Correspondence 2 years. Did while working

Can I apply for PERM and GC on the basis of my education? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a US-equivalent baccalaureate degree. In the US it's a 4-years degree, and you have a 3-years degree. The [USCIS clearly states](https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-third-preference-eb-3):

> Education and experience may not be substituted for a baccalaureate degree.

The MBA is likely irrelevant unless you're working in mid/high management. If you're an engineer/tech professional, the MBA is not a relevant education.

Comment: From the question it sounds like the B. Sc. is a 4-year degree that OP completed in 3 years.  It's also possible to complete US baccalaureate degrees in 3 years under certain circumstances.  It should not matter how much time it actually took to complete, only that the US will accept the degree as equivalent to a US degree.

Comment: @phoog shouldn't wouldn't couldn't doesn't matter. What matters is what **is**. The OP has a transcript that shows a 3-year degree, and I imagine the OP was unable to get an equivalency evaluation that says it's equivalent to the US degree, and that's all that matters. Regardless, from my experience, this is a pretty common issue with Indian degrees as they are in fact 3-year degrees.

Comment: @littleadv - You are right about my B.Sc. It is 3 year course. Do you know if I can apply for some other category or VISA type in order to apply for GC?

Comment: @AK47 My observation is that most work around this by completing a Masters degree (in their field). You did an MBA, which is not helping you probably.

Comment: @littleadv - Isn't MBA a masters degree. Apart from it, my MBA was kind of Part time. I think they need full time.

Comment: @AK47 If you work as an engineer/IT professional then MBA is not *in their field* for you. The degree has to be relevant to the job.